# Circuit drawing more current on PCB

Tags: batteries, pcb, ac, arm

I have a circuit that I developed on breadboard. I have then soldered it on a PCB and it is now drawing more current on PCB compared to when it was on breadboard. I only want to discuss possible reasons for this without going into much detail about the circuit as I haven't changed it before or after soldering on PCB unless someone really wants me to.

Details about the circuit:

- Micro-controller based circuit.
- A couple sensors and a single radio.
- Step-up regulator for powering everything (Pololu 5V).

This is what comes to my mind:

- Flux conducting some current?
- Possible tiny short-circuit somewhere?
- Possible faulty chip after soldering?
- Possible different current consumption with different power supplier? 
  (3.6V lipo battery over a cheap AC 1A 5V adapter)
- Possible larger resistance on breadboard circuit.

The circuit works **fine** so I assume there is no problem with PCB.

On breadboard it was drawing about 28.5mA. Now on PCB it's drawing about 40mA.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: This is not a discussion forum, sorry. Without specific question there is no specific answer.

Comment: Even if this is a place where to ask questions and that's what I'm doing. Generic answers are fine I said I'm okay with discussing. I've seen other people with generic questions being answered were's the deal.

Comment: This site is structured around having a specific question with a "correct" answer. Without circuit details the question is unanswerable, as there are umpteen possible reasons for the discrepancy, and exhaustively listing these to cover every possible circuit is not reasonable.

Comment: You said that the **power** consumption changed but then you talk about changing **current**. Which is it? Please explain your manufacturing and assembly process in detail, if you won't describe the circuit.

Comment: Okay then I will award correct answer to who ever provides me with an exhaustive answer for possible reasons.

Comment: What does "measuring from the sensors" mean? What sensors, and what exactly are they measuring?

Comment: Okay I tried now to make everything as clear as possible. I can add more information if needed.

Comment: What do you get for actual **power** consumption then? What happens if you multiply supply voltage by supply current in both cases?

Comment: If you're expecting "an exhaustive answer for possible reasons", then pretty much by definition your question is too broad for this site (and the reason for my close vote), although it looks to me as if JYelton has found your non-issue.

Comment: Everyone here is so welcome. No wonder there are so many fights on these type of websites. Thanks anyway. The web is always a place full of nice people (engineers).

Comment: @brhans yet someone found the issue with my issue. So thank you for nothing but only exacerbate an honest question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you supplied 5V while the circuit was on a breadboard, and 3.6V while it is on a PCB, that seems to me the biggest explanation of different currents. Having no idea what your circuit is, I'll just calculate if it has the same power in both configurations:

Breadboard: \$P = 5 \times 0.0285 = 142.5\mathrm{mW}\$

PCB: \$P = 3.6 \times 0.04 = 144\mathrm{mW}\$

It looks like the device draws the same *power* so I think you may be seeing a problem that isn't there.